# After Loading TensorFlow dataset, My GPU memory is almost full

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am new to Tensorflow, if the question is too fundamental please forgive me.

My desktop is using GPU Geforce 3060 which has a 12 Gb memory. But when I use the following code to load the dataset, even as small as 'mnist'.

```py
(ds_train), datainfo = tfds.load(
    'mnist',
    split = 'train',
    as_supervised=True,
    data_dir= 'E:/Dataset/',
    download=True,
    shuffle_files=False,
    with_info =True
)
```

I was using the task manager to monitor the GPU memory storage, the picture shows the GPU memory is going to exhaust.
[image]

And if I load a model like vgg16 and do some forward propagation, Vscode will crush and prompt me 'the memory is full'. And even if I only load 50% of the training data, nothing will change, the memory usage purges to almost full.

But in the TensorFlow document [dataset performance](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/performances#large_datasets), In the 'Auto-shard your data across workers (TF)' session, if I set multiple input_pipeline, the situation won't change at all.

```py
input_context = tf.distribute.InputContext(
    input_pipeline_id=1,  # Worker id
    num_input_pipelines=8,  # Total number of workers
)
read_config = tfds.ReadConfig(
    input_context=input_context,
)
(ds_train), datainfo = tfds.load(
    # 'cars196',
    'cats_vs_dogs',
    # split= ['train[:80%]','train[80%:90%]', 'train[90%:]'],
    split = 'train',
    as_supervised=True,
    data_dir= 'E:/Dataset/',
    download=True,
    shuffle_files=False,
    with_info =True,
    read_config = read_config
    # batch_size=BATCH_SIZE
)
```

Comment: By default TensorFlow takes up all of GPU (at least for model traininig. Have you tried [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu#limiting_gpu_memory_growth)?